# Creating a custom control panel just for p.a.registry XML entries

Tags: plone

How it is possible to create a Plone configlet if you only declare your settings as registry.xml?

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.registry only shows you how to do it if you are using schema defined settings.

I.e. how one maps p.a.z3cform Form to registry.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible.

You need to have settings.py file.

Here is an example:

https://github.com/miohtama/silvuple/blob/master/silvuple/settings.py